# General error in mysql pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get the primary key by using `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`but I am getting an error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error`

```
  function logCallDetails($db,$student_id,$currentStory,$currentCall){
        try{
        $query= "INSERT INTO `call`(`student_id`, `story_id`, `call_number`) VALUES ('$student_id','$currentStory','$currentCall');SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();";
        echo $query;
        $result=$db->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        $result = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


        #$result->closeCursor();
        return $result;
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();  
        }
}
```

initialize.php

```
$get_call_id=logCallDetails($db,$student_id,$call_number,$story_id);
            foreach($get_call_id as $row=>$s)
            {
                foreach($s as $k=>$v)
                {
                    echo $k.'->'.$v.'<br/>';
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got 2 separate queries in a single query call. This is NOT allowed for security reasons by the underlying MySQL drivers. You'll have to prepare/execute the `INSERT` and `SELECT` queries separately.

Comment: This is actially perfectly allowed

Comment: The statements can be seperated by a semicolon right ? I think it's possible on PDO. @MarcB

Comment: Has nothing to do with PDO. This is a restriction of the underlying PHP mysql drivers that PDO is using. It's a basic anti-sql injection defense mechanisms, which makes the classic bobby-tables attack impossible on mysql via php.

Comment: There are no "basic anti-sql injection defense mechanisms" and multy-query restriction cannot be count as one.

Comment: like I said, it makes the bobby tables attack impossible. That's *ONE* form of injection attack. I didn't say it makes ALL attacks impossible.

Comment: It is not a form of attack. it is a form of *exploit* of **already successful attack**. It is **too late** to defend if you already failed.

Comment: Fine. An attack MITIGATION technique, then. The fact remains, the OP's query is impossible on MySQL because it's a DRIVER restriction, and nothing you do in PHP will change the fact that multiple queries in a single query()-type call are NOT permitted.

Comment: Such a mitigation is: 1. Too useless. Beside dropping tables there are *other* ways. 2. Still exists in your imagination only. Turn emulation mode on and try to run two queries with semicolon between :)

Comment: As far as I investigated, unlike mysql ext, PDO is using `MYSQL_OPTION_MULTI_STATEMENTS_ON`, while in native mode it's restriction of prepared statement, not driver, is in effect

Answer (score 0):

```
function logCallDetails($db,$student_id,$currentStory,$currentCall){
    $query= "INSERT INTO `call`(`student_id`, `story_id`, `call_number`) 
             VALUES (?,?,?)";
    $result=$db->prepare($query);
    $result->execute(array_slice(func_get_args()));
    return $db->lastInsertId();
}

$get_call_id = logCallDetails($db,$student_id,$call_number,$story_id);
echo $get_call_id;
```

Comment: I get the error Call to undefined method PDO::lastIinsertId()

Comment: lastInsertId it is. you can always check spelling yourself.